# Is there a terminal-only version of a SQL query editor like Sequel Pro?

Tags: sql

I'd like to be able to do everything I can do in Sequel Pro but via a terminal interface. It should be more powerful than the MySQL cli that is just a REPL. I'd like to be able to stage queries and run them selectively from a textarea like I can do in Sequel Pro. It should be able to mange multiple database connections and allow me to select which one I'm connected to. I need it on macOS, Linux, and FreeBSD ideally. Does any program like this exist?

Comment: What OS? What features are you looking for exactly?  If you just want to connect and run queries, the mysqlclient command works great on Linux systems... perhaps also on OS X...

Comment: @ivanivan updated to provide a little more information

Comment: Not really matching all your needs (hence no answer), but worth a look: [mycli](http://mycli.net/index). Doesn't look like there are many alternatives out there for the command line – at least I haven't encountered any yet.